# can we write program to get password of linux user

Tags: java, linux

can we write a program in java to get usernames and passwords

Comment: Please clarify. get usernames from where? get passwords from where? 
What did you try/ paln to do? Do soem thinking, sha<e your results and better your answers you will provoke.

Comment: If it were that easy, nobody would ever use Linux anymore.

Comment: can we also make the program give us their bank account details? :)

Comment: @BoltClock, the thanks wasnt in advance

Comment: -1 bad/unclear description - loss of time to read here.

Comment: @willcodejavaforfood I dont care about bank details, i want Money ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can get usernames by reading /etc/passwd file.

You cannot get passwords unless you try to decrypt them, and that's not practical...

Answer (score 2):

> No, we can't.

Answer (score 0):

Without a brute-force attack and at least a list of the encrypted passwords, you are out of luck.

Also read this
http://www.linux.org/docs/ldp/howto/Security-HOWTO/password-security.html

and this
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcpasswd-file-format/